# calculate date -10 days

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, cmd

I am new in batch script. Currently my file is showing in below format. i want the details output where date should be 10days before the currentdate (means date-10). Currently its is showing in latest date

```
00000064  xxyz                 2013-06-17 14:37:11      
00000065  xxyz                 2013-06-17 14:46:15      
00000066  xxyz                 2013-06-17 14:52:34      
0000006d  xxyz                 2013-06-18 11:17:42      
0000006e  xxyz                 2013-06-18 11:29:57      
0000006f  xxyz                 2013-06-18 11:50:53      
00000070  xxyz                 2013-06-18 12:17:56      
00000074  xxyz                 2013-06-19 11:45:36      
00000001  xxyz                 2013-06-19 15:22:07      
00000002  xxyz                 2013-06-19 16:12:45      
00000003  xxyz                 2013-06-19 16:19:42      
00000006  xxyz                 2013-06-19 20:36:46      
00000008  xxyz                 2013-06-19 23:34:11      
0000000f  xxyz                 2013-06-20 10:49:38      
00000010  xxyz                 2013-06-20 10:50:59      
00000011  xxyz                 2013-06-20 10:52:29      
00000018  xxyz                 2013-06-20 15:58:24      
0000006e  xxyz                 2013-06-25 07:11:00      
0000007f  xxyz                 2013-06-26 08:55:36      
00000080  xxyz                 2013-06-26 09:08:14      
00000081  xxyz                 2013-06-26 09:28:57      
00000082  xxyz                 2013-06-26 13:49:31      
00000083  xxyz                 2013-06-26 14:00:53      
00000087  xxyz                 2013-06-27 10:00:27      
0000008b  xxyz                 2013-06-27 12:40:53      
00000091  xxyz                 2013-06-27 15:32:15
```

Comment: StackOverflow really isn't a site for "Here's what I need. Please write the code for me." questions. Please do some research (there are lots of questions here if you search on `batch-file` or just click the `batch-file` tag) and make an effort to figure it out yourself. Once you've done so, you can post what you've tried here and ask us how to help you get it working. Good luck. :-)

Comment: You mentioned that the example is your current output.  What is your code?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for Windows:

```
awk -F"[-: ]+" "{print $1,$2,\"\t\t\t\",strftime(\"%F %T\",mktime($3\" \"$4\" \"$5\" \"$6\" \"$7\" \"$8)-864000)}" file
```

```
>awk -F"[-: ]+" "{print $1,$2,\"\t\t\t\",strftime(\"%F %T\",mktime($3\" \"$4\" \"$5\" \"$6\" \"$7\" \"$8)-864000)}" file
00000064 xxyz                    2013-06-07 14:37:11
00000065 xxyz                    2013-06-07 14:46:15
00000066 xxyz                    2013-06-07 14:52:34
0000006d xxyz                    2013-06-08 11:17:42
0000006e xxyz                    2013-06-08 11:29:57
0000006f xxyz                    2013-06-08 11:50:53
00000070 xxyz                    2013-06-08 12:17:56
00000074 xxyz                    2013-06-09 11:45:36
00000001 xxyz                    2013-06-09 15:22:07
00000002 xxyz                    2013-06-09 16:12:45
00000003 xxyz                    2013-06-09 16:19:42
00000006 xxyz                    2013-06-09 20:36:46
00000008 xxyz                    2013-06-09 23:34:11
0000000f xxyz                    2013-06-10 10:49:38
00000010 xxyz                    2013-06-10 10:50:59
00000011 xxyz                    2013-06-10 10:52:29
00000018 xxyz                    2013-06-10 15:58:24
0000006e xxyz                    2013-06-15 07:11:00
0000007f xxyz                    2013-06-16 08:55:36
00000080 xxyz                    2013-06-16 09:08:14
00000081 xxyz                    2013-06-16 09:28:57
00000082 xxyz                    2013-06-16 13:49:31
00000083 xxyz                    2013-06-16 14:00:53
00000087 xxyz                    2013-06-17 10:00:27
0000008b xxyz                    2013-06-17 12:40:53
00000091 xxyz                    2013-06-17 15:32:15
```

seconds per 10 days = 864000

Comment: Thanks for the answer but AWK its showing error that awk is recognised as an internal or external command

Comment: `awk` comes from Unix and is available at GNUwin32.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general purpose VBS script in a batch file that can calculate dates.

```
:: Date foward & backward
@echo off
if "%~2"=="" (
echo to get todays date use         call "%~n0" today 0
echo to get yesterdays date use     call "%~n0" today -1
echo to get 25 days before 19441213 call "%~n0" 1944/12/13 -25
echo to get 1250 days in the future call "%~n0" today 1250
echo.
echo Add a third parameter if you want a separator in the date string
echo EG: to use - as in YYYY-MM-DD for today's date
echo     call "%~n0" today 0 -
echo.
pause
goto :EOF)

set date1=%1
set qty=%2
set separator=%~3
if /i "%date1%" EQU "TODAY" (set date1=now) else (set date1="%date1%")
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%qty%,%date1%)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+month(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set result=%%a
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
endlocal& set day=%result:~0,4%%separator%%result:~4,2%%separator%%result:~6,2%
echo %%day%% is set to "%day%" (without the quotes)
pause
```